# Show button under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple script

I want to change the condition to

```
if (text.includes("admin")) {
 //Then a continue button will appear..
```

how to make it?

```js
function check() {
  var text = document.getElementById("wrd").value;

  if (text == "") {
    alert("Error: The url field is Empty.");
  } else if (text.includes("admin")) {
    alert("DONE");
  } else {
    alert("ERROR : This url was not found.");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="wrd" class="wrd" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="myword...">
  <button id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" onclick="check()" style="display:none;">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How are you supposed to invoke the function when the button is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. NEVER call anything in a form `submit`
2. Use the `input` event handler
3. use the submit event handler - note that enter will submit the form if the button is just hidden instead of disabled. Also note that in your case that is fine
4. make the field required

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // on page load
  document.getElementById("wrd").addEventListener("input", function() {
    const text = this.value.trim();
    document.getElementById("subbut").hidden = !text.includes("admin")
  })
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    const text = this.wrd.value;
    if (!text.includes("admin")) {
      e.preventDefault(); // stop submit
      alert("ERROR : This word was not found.");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="wrd" name="wrd" class="wrd" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="myword..." required>
  <button id="subbut" class="submit" type="submit" hidden>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script code. I hope this will help you.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("wrd");
var btn = document.getElementById("submit");

function check() {
  const textValue = text.value
 if (textValue.includes("admin")) {
    btn.style.display = "block"
  } 
}
```

```html
<input id="wrd" class="wrd" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="myword..." oninput="check()">
<button id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" style="display:none">SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: User will have to click on something else for this to work

Comment: "oninput" event called every time when user enters any value in textbox.

Comment: I know. That is why I use it but never inline